# Disable SSLv3 network wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl

I know HTTPS isn't supported, but sadly we support SSLv3. Can we disable this pls?

Reason:

- [SSL3 "POODLE" Vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Done](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/522197758888124416), [status-precompleted](/questions/tagged/status-precompleted)

As verification, [the SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=meta.stackexchange.com) shows:

```
Protocols
-----------------
TLS 1.2      Yes
TLS 1.1      Yes
TLS 1.0      Yes
SSL 3         No
SSL 2         No
```

Comment: You sure? It still shows positive to me. :/

Comment: Support for SSLv3 comes back negative for me.

Comment: Sorry, I was misreading. OpenSSL says "New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is", but if I use `-ssl3` it wont connect at all.